# Swift Generic Issue extending API

Tags: swift, generics

In Swift I need to be able to generically work with the various `Token<T>` given to me by an API.

Note that I'm Using Swift 5.8.

The API defines the following (only showing relevant parts):

```
public struct Token<T> : Codable, Equatable, Hashable { }

public struct Application : Equatable, Hashable {
    public let token: ApplicationToken?
}

public struct ActivityCategory : Equatable, Hashable {
    public let token: ActivityCategoryToken?
}

public struct WebDomain : Equatable, Hashable {
    public let token: WebDomainToken?
}

public typealias ApplicationToken = Token<Application>
public typealias ActivityCategoryToken = Token<ActivityCategory>
public typealias WebDomainToken = Token<WebDomain>


// Data the API gives me:
struct ActivitySelection {
    public var applicationTokens: Set<ApplicationToken>
    public var categoryTokens: Set<ActivityCategoryToken>
    public var webDomainTokens: Set<WebDomainToken>
}
```

**I tried doing this:**

```
// My custom ActivityType:
enum ActivityType {
    case Applications
    case Categories
    case WebDomains
}

// My API Extension
extension ActivitySelection {
    func tokensFor<T>(activity:ActivityType) -> [Token<T>] {
        let array: [Token<T>]
        switch activity {
            case .Applications:
                array = Array(self.applicationTokens) as! [Token<T>]
            case .Categories:
                array = Array(self.categoryTokens) as! [Token<T>]
            case .WebDomains:
                array = Array(self.webDomainTokens) as! [Token<T>]
        }
        // sort before returning here removed for simplicity
        return array
    }
}

let selection = ActivitySelection() // returns with data
```

Then when I try to use my extension:

```
let tokens = selection.tokensFor(activity: .Applications)
```

I get this error:

- `XCode Error: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

If I try this:

```
    func tokensFor<T>(activity:Activities) -> [Token<T>] {
        let array: [Token<T>]
        switch activity {
            case .Applications:
                array = Array(self.applicationTokens)
            case .Categories:
                array = Array(self.categoryTokens)
            case .WebDomains:
                array = Array(self.webDomainTokens)
        }
        // sort before returning here
        return array
    }
```

I get:

- `Cannot assign value of type '[ApplicationToken]' (aka 'Array<Token<Application>>') to type '[Token<T>]'`
- `Cannot assign value of type '[ActivityCategoryToken]' (aka 'Array<Token<ActivityCategory>>') to type '[Token<T>]'`
- `Cannot assign value of type '[WebDomainToken]' (aka 'Array<Token<WebDomain>>') to type '[Token<T>]'`

I've also tried it this way:

```
    func tokensFor(activity:Activities) -> [Token<Any>] {
        let array: [Token<Any>]
        switch activity {
            case .Applications:
                array = Array(self.applicationTokens)
            case .Categories:
                array = Array(self.categoryTokens)
            case .WebDomains:
                array = Array(self.webDomainTokens)
        }
        // sort before returning here
        return array
    }
```

But I get errors:

- `Cannot assign value of type '[ApplicationToken]' (aka 'Array<Token<Application>>') to type '[Token<Any>]'`
- `Cannot assign value of type '[ActivityCategoryToken]' (aka 'Array<Token<ActivityCategory>>') to type '[Token<Any>]'`
- `Cannot assign value of type '[WebDomainToken]' (aka 'Array<Token<WebDomain>>') to type '[Token<Any>]'`

How can I make this work? I thought generics was the solution to this very problem.

Since `Token<T>` is already a generic type, how do I use that to work with the 3 different token types generically?

Comment: Why is `tokensFor` even needed? People can just access any one of those three properties they want. Are you trying to pass something into `tokensFor` that is only known at runtime? Then generics wouldn't be useful at all.

Comment: Also0, can you show how `T` is used inside `Token<T>`? If you indeed are going to pass something that is only runtime into `tokensFor`, then you likely need to return a type that is not generic - all the `T`s will be replaced with `Any`.

Comment: tokensFor is for passing tokens to a SwiftUI View builder for displaying the tokens.  As for Token<T> I don't have any implementation details for it. What the API defines is what I put in my post.

Comment: "tokensFor is for passing tokens to a SwiftUI View builder for displaying the tokens." Can you show *how* you do that?

Comment: The view builder uses a ForEach to iterate over the sorted array of tokens. Exact details aren't too relevant as I'm just trying to figure out how to get the view builder the data it needs. Yes I could write  separate view builders for each token type, but I'd love to figure out how to handle this more generically and not duplicate a bunch of code.

Comment: I think we are getting closer to the solution. Can you show how you would write "3 separate view builders"? I think that part could be refactored into a generic view, and then you can make 3 of those generic views: `TheGenericView<Application>() TheGenericView<ActivityCategory>() TheGenericView<WebDomain>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This signature does not mean what you think it means:

```
func tokensFor<T>(activity:ActivityType) -> [Token<T>] {
```

This says that the caller can pick any type that can possibly exist (a String, Int, random struct they just defined, UIViewController, anything), and this function promises to return a Token wrapping that type. And this will all be decided statically, at compile-time. That's not how Token works, and it's not what you mean.

Instead, the goal is to return a Token type that is only known at runtime. That is the standard use for a protocol.

```
protocol TokenType {
    // Here you would generally put any methods the caller needs to be 
    // able to call on the returned token.
}

extension Token: TokenType {
    // This can probably be empty, but if Token needs some new methods to
    // conform to TokenType, add them here.
}

extension ActivitySelection {
    // Now return an Array of "any kind of Token, known at runtime"
    func tokensFor(activity: ActivityType) -> [any TokenType] {
        let array: [any TokenType]
        switch activity {
            case .Applications:
                array = Array(self.applicationTokens)
            case .Categories:
                array = Array(self.categoryTokens)
            case .WebDomains:
                array = Array(self.webDomainTokens)
        }
        // sort before returning here removed for simplicity
        return array
    }
}
```

Comment: ```var tokens:[any ActivityToken]``` ```ForEach(tokens) { token in { //do something}``` Gets `Type 'any ActivityToken' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'` even though I made ActivityToken (and associated types) conform to identifiable.

Comment: @Jay that's because protocols can't conform to themselves. `[any TokenType]` is an array of anything that conforms to `TokenType`. There's nothing to constrain their `id` properties to the same type. It might be OK if you can constrain `ID` to always be the same and define it in a protocol extension.

Comment: So how do I get this to work? The types in the API all conform to hashable and so I've tried to do `ForEach(tokens, id: \.self.hashed) { }` but because of using any ActivityToken as the type, it doesn't seem to see the conformance.  Even if I make ActivityToken (and relevant types conform to hashable/identifiable it still doesn't work. Some solutions I've seen propose making a property wrapper struct (or using  Hashable instead of Any). I've also tried using some TokenType instead of Any TokenType.

Comment: It very much depends on what your ForEach looks like. I suspect you're trying to fix the problem in the wrong place. You mention "Yes I could write separate view builders for each token type." I think what you really mean here is that you could make a generic view builder that accepts a token type. Or you need to extract reusable code across related token view builders using a protocol extension. Or you can use a generic that accepts up to 10 types (which is how ViewBuilder works), but that's kind of obnoxious to write. It very much depends on your calling code, which you don't provide.

Comment: I recommend going down the road of creating a ViewBuilder for a couple of types, and then see what can be extracted into a generic ViewBuilder (or just a View that accepts a token. It's not obvious whether you need a ViewBuilder here)

Comment: I edited my original question with an update on what I’ve done. Love any thoughts on how to make it work.

Comment: Your example is really unclear what would go in the `ForEach`. How does `activity` get set? Is it a single value for the View (is it determined at compile-time or runtime?), or can there be a mix of different kinds of Tokens in the list? I still have a strong felling you're solving for the wrong problem here. All your example code just returns a single token, so it's not obvious what this Array and ForEach are doint.

Comment: `ForEach(tokens, id: \.self.hashValue) { }` works. Problem was the key path `.hashed`. Stupid mistake late night coding.  Thanks for all your help!!! So happy this is working and now I understand a lot more about `any` and `some` as well as swift generics, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why using an `enum` doesn't work is that enum values could only be known at runtime:

```
let tokens = tokensFor(activity: randomlyGenerateAnActivity())
```

If `randomlyGenerateAnActivity` randomly chooses one of the three cases, what would be the compile-time type of `tokens`? The compiler cannot know.

One solution would be to make such a type, a non-generic type that wraps a `Token<T>`, replacing everything in `Token<T>` that involves `T` with something similar, except `T` is replaced with `Any`. Since you don't want to show what members `Token<T>` has, I can't give any code examples for this.

Another solution would be to make `tokensFor` take a *metatype* as a parameter.

```
// make Application, ActivityCategory, and WebDomain conform to this
public protocol TokenType {
    var token: Token<Self>? { get }
}

extension ActivitySelection {
    func tokensFor<T: TokenType>(_ tokenType: T.Type) -> [Token<T>] {
        let array: [Token<T>]
        if tokenType == Application.self {
            array = Array(self.applicationTokens) as! [Token<T>]
        } else if tokenType == ActivityCategory.self {
            array = Array(self.categoryTokens) as! [Token<T>]
        } else if tokenType == WebDomain.self {
            array = Array(self.webDomainTokens) as! [Token<T>]
        } else {
            fatalError("Invalid Token Type")
        }
        // sort before returning here removed for simplicity
        return array
    }
}
```

Now the type that `tokensFor` will return is always known at compile time.

Note that instead of using `if...else if` to check the type, you could also add a static property in the protocol that returns the corresponding key path:

```
// implement this property in each of the three types
static var activitySelectionKeyPath: KeyPath<ActivitySelection, Set<Token<Self>>> { get }
```

Then you can just get the array in `tokensFor` from `self[keyPath: T.activitySelectionKeyPath]`.

---

Since you are displaying the tokens in a SwiftUI view, you should make a generic `View`, and pass that generic parameter into `tokensFor`:

```
public struct SomeGenericView<T: TokenType>: View {
    let activitySelection = ActivitySelection()
    
    public var body: some View {
        ForEach(activitySelection.tokensFor(T.self), id: \.something) { token in
            Text("\(token)")
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can make three of this `SomeGenericView`:

```
// in a parent view...
public var body: some View {
    SomeGenericView<Application>()
    SomeGenericView<ActivityCategory>()
    SomeGenericView<WebDomain>()
}
```

Comment: There's some interesting code here and I appreciate your answer as playing with your solution has really helped me better understand generic functions.  I did get a version based on your answer mostly working, though I still ran into some issues.  Ultimately, the other answer which I accepted seemed to work easier without other issues.  Also, note that you can use `Switch` in your case if you do it like: `case is Application.Type:` which IMO is much more elegant that the  `if/else if` syntax.

Comment: One other note: `randomlyGenerateAnActivity` can `-> any ActivityToken` and then it would work.